Critique of my proof by Contrapositive : Tournament Champion
(I would like confirmation/clarity on:
i. Whether it is acceptable to pick an extreme case of a disjunction to prove a theorem
ii. Whether my negation of the definition of a tournament champion is correct.
)
A tournament is a contest among n > 0 players. Each player plays exactly one game against each other player, and either wins or loses the game.
A tournament champion is a player c where, for each player p that c lost to, there is a player q where c won against q and q won against c
Theorem: Let T be an arbitrary tournament. If c won more games than anyone else in T or is tied for winning the greatest number of games, then c is a tournament champion in T.
PROOF:
We will prove the contrapositive of the original statement, namely that if c is not a tournament champion, then every player will win more games than c. To do so, assume that c is not a champion. We will show that the number of games won by c is less than the number of games won by every player.
Since c is not a champion, for every player q, either c lost to q or there exists some player p who beat q. Take an extreme case where c is not a champion, namely that c lost to each player. Since c lost to each player, it will have no wins, and every other player will have atleast one win. From this we gather that each player will have more wins than c, which is what we set out to prove.
QED
Thank you.
